# How to center divs next to each other with equal space around each

Tags: css, layout, positioning

my two identically wide divs are not displaying next to each other. I have triad few CSS approaches, but it did not work. Can some one tell me where im going wrong writh this one?

My HTML is:

```
 <article class="left">
                    <header>
                       <h2 class="headline">A little bit about me</h2>
                    </header>
                            <p class="custom_font">After working for more than 10 years at a numerous five star hotels and restaurants 
                               around the world as a pastry chef, I decided to start my own litte business to give the 
                               chance for every one to taste my favourite recipes from all those years.</p>
            </article>
             <article class="right">
                    <header>
                         <h2 class="headline">Article title</h2>
                    </header>
                            <p class="custom_font">At My Treat we handmake delicious treats made from finest organic ingredients. 
                               Always fresh never frozen.</p>
            </article>
```

And my CSS:

```
.left {
float: right;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: if you're bored here do something else elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `margin: 0 auto;`

With `margin: 0 auto` you are centering the divs

Comment: Thats the one. Thnk you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use one class?
Example:

```
article {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

You can see the effect [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uMTEA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you should change a little your html.
try this one:

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="class.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="left">

                       <h2 class="headline">A little bit about me</h2>

                            <p class="custom_font">After working for more than 10 years at a numerous five star hotels and restaurants 
                               around the world as a pastry chef, I decided to start my own litte business to give the 
                               chance for every one to taste my favourite recipes from all those years.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="right">

                         <h2 class="headline">Article title</h2>

                            <p class="custom_font">At My Treat we handmake delicious treats made from finest organic ingredients. 
                               Always fresh never frozen.</p>
            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

css stylesheet is the same:

```
.left {
float: right;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```